# Excel 'OFFLINE COPY' Workbook is in read-only mode

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to detect whether the workbook is an `OFFLINE COPY` as showed on the picture below.

Maybe with vba code ?

The property `ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly` returns `False`

[image]

With a 'real' read-only workbook, the event `Workbook_BeforeSave` is never reached. With the `OFFLINE COPY` read-only mode as I talk here, the event `Workbook_BeforeSave` is reached but returns the message below:

[image]

So the behaviour is different. I need to detect it with vba.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running the macro from the workbook that's possibly an Offline Copy thus referring to it as ThisWorkbook?
How about this work-around: if trying to save the workbook errors out, go to a different block of code and execute what's needed there.

`On Error GoTo ErrorRecovery
 ThisWorkbook.Save
 ErrorRecovery:
 'code for whatever needs to be done if the file can't be saved.`

I couldn't recreate your issue, but hope this helps!